# How can i create an new activity on imagebutton click?

Tags: android, image, button, imagebutton

Does someone know how I can start a new activity when image button click?

Comment: what have you tried ? Copy your own question and ask to google. You can find tons of results.

Comment: you can't create a activity you can start one,also please do some search before you post your question

Comment: try to type "android start new activity" on google and press enter

Comment: Two questions into one. Learn how to code the click event, then how to start new activity. Google each. Done and done. Seriously, no need to stack something like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
 ImageButton mainButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.mainButton);
mainButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

 @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
 Intent intent=new intent(this,NewActivityname.class);
    startActivity(intent);

 }
});}
```

Add your newactivity class in androidmanifest file